# App crashes because of out of memory

Tags: ios, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting, afnetworking, didreceivememorywarning

[image: Instruments app]

I have a **Instagram-like** app with endless feed and the the camera. I am using `ARC`. For loading (and caching) images I'm using `AFNetworking`.

When i scroll feed, it's alloc and alloc a lot of memory, sometimes it's released. So if my app takes more than 10-13mb and I open Camera, it is crashing. 
My feed is an `NSMutableArray` consisting of entities like this:

```
@interface Post : NSObject 
@property (readonly) NSString *postId;
@property (readonly) NSURL *imageURL;
@property (readonly) NSString *text;
@end
```

What am I doing wrong? And what should I do in didreceivememorywarning method?

Comment: This question cannot be answered, unfortunately, as it's not specific enough. We can only give you hints, like run the static analyzer and try to analyze by hand who will be holding which objects. You do have a kind of memory leak, but endlessly putting stuff into an NSMutableArray and never removing anything from it is also a kind of memory leak, for example.

Answer (score 0):

When you receive didReceiveMemoryWarning, you can dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

```
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{    
    [self setBackBtn:nil];
    [self setDataSource:nil];
    [self setPendingDataSource:nil];
    [self setSelectionView:nil];
    [self setTitleForFormBarButtons:nil];
    [self setType:nil];

    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}
```